# Android background image stretching

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, android-imageview

I have a problem with my Android app background image. It is large enough: 800 x 470 px, but the thing is - it is getting stretched to the screen dimensions, when I use it as a Layout background attribute (I use LinearLayout, by the way). I found a solution to use an ImageView (with centerCrop scaleType), but it crops the very very centre of the image, and I want to crop the LEFT part of it. Offset by X axis helps, but if I switch to horizontal layout - it looks like a crap. Is there any solution that would help me NOT to use two separate background images ? Or it is impossible.

Thank you very much for your answers. :)

Comment: if you are using plain image then use bitmap repeat.

Comment: It is not plain, unfortunately :(

Comment: post the image at least.

Comment: http://www.google.ru/imgres?q=twitter+background&um=1&hl=ru&newwindow=1&sa=N&biw=1920&bih=962&tbm=isch&tbnid=_0xJcj4Zll0feM:&imgrefurl=http://www.smashingbuzz.com/2010/06/40-really-inspiring-twitter-background-designs/&docid=LtlB3uWXG72QLM&imgurl=http://www.smashingbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Lu%2525C3%2525ADs-Filipe-Borges-twitter-background.jpg&w=600&h=520&ei=cRKlT5TiB4Xh4QTG1t2iCQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=192&vpy=39&dur=620&hovh=209&hovw=241&tx=117&ty=131&sig=102064691840880663530&page=1&tbnh=144&tbnw=188&start=0&ndsp=40&ved=1t:429,r:24,s:0,i:124    this is the background I want

Answer (score 1):

Android devices come in many different screen sizes, so its best not to have a fixed size background.

You could use a 9-patch image and define areas in the image that should stretch, you can learn about this here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Of course, using a 9-patch might compromise the background images design, so you would have to make adjustments to make it 9-patch friendly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks :) Is it the only solution possible in this situation ?

Comment: Well you could do what you proposed and change the scaleType to a suitable value but it might not work in all cases, maybe you could also letter box it with some margin, set the scaleType to center.